# Uninstalling MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, installing

I installed MiKTeX 2.9 on windows 7 but I was not able to compile files in Texmaker. Then I installed TeX Live, which is working fine. Now when I try to uninstall MiKTeX from Control panel, it gives following error: **"Windows API error 5: Access is denied"**.
How to uninstall it now. I am beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall as administrator?

Comment: I opened control panel and right clicked on the program and tried Uninstall. How can I uninstall as admininstrator.

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you have a standard installation. Go to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\internal\`. Right-click on `uninstall_admin.exe` and select `Execute as Administrator`.

If you have MiKTeX 32 bit, go to`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\internal\`.

Comment: I followed  the above steps but it gives an error: The IniTeXMF executable could not be found

Comment: I'm puzzled… Try to execute `uninstall.exe` (as administrator).

Comment: Did that as well. The error is same.

Comment: Perhaps your installation was buggy? It's strange you couldn't compile from TeXmaker.

Comment: Check out this ticket on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2380/
Alternatively try the new MiKTeX setup utility (command line) to uninstall: http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/miktexsetup-2.9.6073.zip

Comment: I had a similar issue: I installed MiKTeX without admin rights and only `uninstall.exe` works (without starting it as admin).

Comment: The `uninstall_admin.exe` would not work. I was able to uninstall using the `uninstall.exe` in the folder you suggested. (I had installed the program as user.) The uninstall process went through. However, the program icon is still there in the start menu and the program still opens and works despite having been uninstalled using the `uninstall.exe` command, which had completed successfully with no errors. Would like to do a reinstall but not sure what steps to take now. The program is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Windows API (application programming interface?) error as above. I dragged the entire MiKTeX 2.9 folder to the trash and then went to the "Change or remove a program" option from Control Panel. MiKTeX 2.9 was still on the list, but when I clicked "Uninstall", I got a message saying that it may already be uninstalled and asked whether I'd like to remove it from the list of Programs - I clicked "Yes".

It seems to be gone!

Comment: Hmmm... so you deleted MiKTeX and you can still compile? That's odd. Is this at all helpful?