# LaTeX not compiling, trying to reinstall MiKTex and Texmaker but too many MiKTeX files?

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, compiling, texmaker

I've been having trouble with Texmaker after years of using it -- it never compiles just endlessly processing or whatever, and there is no error. I've never come across this before, so I tried to uninstall/reinstall but that didn't work so I did that again with MiKTex as well. I did this a few times and nothing is working so I decided to uninstall MiKTeX again and then look in my files for MiKTeX stuff and found a lot a lot of files! Do I need to delete all of these before reinstalling? I'm at a loss right now and confused as to why there are so many. I also tried texstudio instead of texmaker and that didn't make any difference.

[image: 554 files related to MiKTeX!]

Comment: It seems you can just remove all of these before re-installing, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418805/cannot-uninstall-miktex-2-9-on-windows-10-due-to-administrative-shared-setup for a related question. However, the issue that you describe might just be caused by a problematic document being stuck in a loop, maybe nothing is/was actually broken.

Comment: @Marijn ok I'll probably look at that then. With regard to one document being in a loop, it is all the ones I tried that have all previously compiled (some for years) not working as well as new ones that I know are not in a loop :/